# When should I submit site content to Google analytics

Tags: seo

I have purchased a website domain and I hosted a "Coming soon" page for the website.
I am looking forward to go live soon and I am working on the actual website in my dev environment. 
Should I submit the dummy website content for [Google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url)? or should I wait until I deploy the actual website?

I will configure SSL certificate for the site, will I need to re-submit the URL after that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: SEO is in the tagging list and it's a valid topic I guess.

Comment: Click on the tag and read it

Comment: You are correct, sorry about that. Tnx :).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a SEO not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the site now and ask Google to crawl again later when it is up and running

more info to ask for Crawl https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1352276

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Anytime,. You can submit your site/blog to Google Analytic. because this is most important part of SEO by Google ( natural)

let's check my site :- http://www.onlyloudest.com

I was launched this site before 1 month are see performance with natural SEO .

Answer (score 0):

Submitting your website to Google Analytics does a lot for your website. 
Here are the things that you would get in return -

1. Reports on audience traffic (social, referral, organic, etc.)
2. Along with submitting to Analytics, you can also submit your website to Google Webmaster Tools. This helps more because it improves your SEO. As soon as you submit your website sitemap to Webmaster Tools, Google indexes all pages on your website into its database. So, now Google knows that it must display your website as well when a search term is typed in by the user. 
   Not only this, each time you post something new (a new page or a new post) the sitemap gets updated and Google is notified about the change in your website.

Google loves websites that are frequently changed and updated. Frequently updating websites are ranked better. But Google must be informed about those updates. That can only happen through Webmaster Tools and not Analytics. Analytics is only useful for you to study your website's performance.

Try my website at http://www.a100websolutions.in for more information on these stuff, SEO and SMM.